# How to make two layers with different CRS line up correctly?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have an Excel Table with Lat/Long information. Its lat/long of this coordinate System: **UTM zone 29n**

My population density map instead is this coordinate system: **UTM WGS84**

Example: Barcleyville: Lon = 585242 / Lat = 517100

---

What I tried to do:

I loaded the pop_density data and changed the projection to WGS84 / UTM zone 29n : EPSG32629. Afterwards I loaded the CSV-Data with the same projection but it's still not overlapping. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Try using **Save As...** on the pop_density layer and save it as a new shapefile with the correct projection. Then load the new shapefile to see if it overlaps correctly.

Comment: Thats not working. Still the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is

> I loaded the pop_density data and changed the projection to WGS84 / UTM zone 29n : EPSG32629.

Do NOT change the CRS in the layer properties! Just make sure that the pop layer is set to UTM WGS84, and the CSV layer to UTM zone 29n, and enable on-the-fly reprojection in the project properties.

Comment: I'm still waiting for a big warning inside the `Set Layer CRS` dialogie box. Most new users misunderstand that menu entry.

Comment: Something like "Are you sure that you want to change the layer CRS? This does NOT reproject the geometries!"? With a "I understand what I'm doing, leave me alone!" checkbox :D

Comment: Exactly! I'm sure most developers don't know what pitfall they offer here.

Comment: @AndreJ I've started a thread on the qgis-ux mailing list